# Hungarian/munkres algorithm that is able to not link a point based on a max "price"

Tags: python, video-tracking, hungarian-algorithm

i have been using some of the hungarian/munkres algorithms that have been implemented in python (munkres package and scipy linear_sum_assignment to be specific) and they both work well (they are based on the same C implementation i think anyway), however they are lacking a feature i specifically need.

to give some context i am tracking points from one image to another, so the cost matrix is the distance between a point in image 1 to all the points in image 2.

the issue arises in a very specific case, which is if a point from image 1 is lost in the second image, but a new different point is detected as well in image 2, then one of the image 1 points is always matched with the new point. and this is the hungarian algorithm working as intended, dont get me wrong. however what i need is for the hungarian algorithm to return a "no match" for a point if the point it wants to match it with is too far away. in matlab there is an example of this on the file exchange called simpletracker.m, and the munkres implementation there can allow for a case where theres no good link. so even if you have two images with say 5 particles, it might only link 2 of those particles, cause you can use a max linking distance parameter to decide whether assignment should be made or not.

as a simple example, if we have an image1 with two points at (1,1) and (10,1), and for the sake of arguement we know they will move one pixel right in the next image, so we expect them to be at (2,1) and (11,1) in image 2, and the hungarian algorithm will easily link the correct particles if they are found in the second image. however the issue arises if one of them isnt found, say the point at (11,1) and instead a random noise point or a new point emerging in the video is found at say (20,1). then the hungarian algorithm will link the points (1,1) and (2,1) as intended, but will now also link (10,1) to (20,1).

so in the matlab implementation you can choose a max linking distance value and then set the cost matrix entries to infinity, and if only one particle can be assigned, then thats ok and the algorithm only returns that one link. In the munkres.py package, there is something called DISALLOWED, however as soon as this prevents an assignment for every point, the algorithm fails.
e.g. the difference matrix would be [[1, 9^2],[8^2, 10^2]]. if we set 70 as the max linking distance then the matrix is [[1, DISALLOWED],[64, DISALLOWED]]
which means the only valid assignment is point 1 in image 1 (1,1) to point 1 in image2 (2,1). the munkres algorithm however will just return UnsolvableMatrix: Matrix cannot be solved! since it cant link the second point.

so sorry for the wall of text and possible confusion. what im asking is if anyone knows of a munkres implementation that can allow for non-assignment which has already been implemented in python?
alternatively, what would the best course of action be to deal with wrongly matched points? i was thinking i could try to filter out outliers after assignment has been made, or potentially remove columns from the distance matrix after it has been calculated if all the values are DISALLOWED, however im not sure if this would be robust enough to cover all possible cases.

Comment: Why not get the result, and then check the distances given by the result and remove all of them that are too far? I'm pretty sure you can do that in one line in Python.

Comment: yeah after all the links have been identified based on the distance matrix i go through and assign identities, and in the process of doing this i can just go back and do a check on the distance and if its too long i dont link the source points to the target points. simple solution and seems to work well. just easy to get stuck trying to replicate the exact way you did something on another platform, even if other equally good solutions exist, and thats the trap i fell into. thanks!